# conan doesn't upload export/conanfile.py to remote

Tags: conan

I have created customized OpenCV package using conan package manager and uploaded it to a remote storage.

Workflow:

1. create package

   ```
   cd c:\path\to\conanfile.py
   conan create . smart/4.26 --profile ue4
   ```
2. Export with `conan export . opencv-ue4/3.4.0@smart/4.26`

   Result:

   ```
   c:\path\> conan export . opencv-ue4/3.4.0@smart/4.26
   [HOOK - attribute_checker.py] pre_export(): WARN: Conanfile doesn't have 'url'. It is recommended to add it as attribute
   Exporting package recipe
   opencv-ue4/3.4.0@smart/4.26 exports_sources: Copied 3 '.patch' files: cmakes.patch, check_function.patch, typedefs.patch
   opencv-ue4/3.4.0@smart/4.26: The stored package has not changed
   opencv-ue4/3.4.0@smart/4.26: Exported revision: ceee251590f4bf50c4ff48f6dc27c2ed
   ```
3. I upload everything to the remote:

   ```
   c:\path> conan upload -r bart opencv-ue4/3.4.0@rs7-smart/4.26 --all
   Uploading to remote 'bart':
   Uploading opencv-ue4/3.4.0@smart/4.26 to remote 'bart'
   Recipe is up to date, upload skipped
   Uploading package 1/1: 1d79899922d252aec6da136ce61bff640124c1c4 to 'bart'
   Uploaded conan_package.tgz -> opencv-ue4/3.4.0@smart/4.26:1d79 [23667.97k]
   Uploaded conaninfo.txt -> opencv-ue4/3.4.0@smart/4.26:1d79 [0.75k]
   Uploaded conanmanifest.txt -> opencv-ue4/3.4.0@smart/4.26:1d79 [11.81k]
   ```

Our remote storage runs on the Artifactory, and I can see in a browser that `conanfile.py` is not listed anywhere.

I can also verify that directory `C:\Users\user\.conan\data\opencv-ue4\3.4.0\smart\4.26\export` on my Windows PC does contain both `conanfile.py` and `conanmanifest.txt`

I am using Windows PC for doing all above.

Now I'm trying to consume that package on another machine, running Ubuntu Linux.

Here is my `conanfile.txt`

```
[requires]
opencv-ue4/3.4.0@smart/4.26

[generators]
json
```

Command and results

```
> conan install -g json . opencv-ue4/3.4.0@smart/4.26
Configuration:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=gcc
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++
compiler.version=9
os=Linux
os_build=Linux
[options]
[build_requires]
[env]

opencv-ue4/3.4.0@smart/4.26: Not found in local cache, looking in remotes...
opencv-ue4/3.4.0@smart/4.26: Trying with 'bart'...
Downloading conanmanifest.txt completed [0.33k]
opencv-ue4/3.4.0@-smart/4.26: Downloaded recipe revision 0
ERROR: opencv-ue4/3.4.0@smart/4.26: Cannot load recipe.
Error loading conanfile at '/home/user/.conan/data/opencv-ue4/3.4.0/smart/4.26/export/conanfile.py': /home/user/.conan/data/opencv-ue4/3.4.0/smart/4.26/export/conanfile.py not found!
```

Running `ls -la /home/user/.conan/data/opencv-ue4/3.4.0/smart/4.26/export/` shows that the directory indeed contains only file `conanmanifest.txt`

Below is the relevant part of the `conanfile.py` that I've used to build the package

```
from conans import ConanFile, CMake, tools

class OpenCVUE4Conan(ConanFile):
    name = "opencv-ue4"
    version = "3.4.0"
    url = ""
    description = "OpenCV custom build for UE4"
    license = "BSD"
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    generators = "cmake"
    exports_sources = 'patches/cmakes.patch', 'patches/check_function.patch', 'patches/typedefs.patch'
    
    def requirements(self):
        self.requires("ue4util/ue4@adamrehn/profile")
        self.requires("zlib/ue4@adamrehn/{}".format(self.channel))
        self.requires("UElibPNG/ue4@adamrehn/{}".format(self.channel))

    def cmake_flags(self):
        flags = [
            "-DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=OFF",
           # cut 
        ]

        return flags

    def source(self):
        self.run("git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git -b {}".format(self.version))
        self.run("git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git -b {}".format(self.version))

    def build(self):
        # Patch OpenCV to avoid build errors
        for p in self.exports_sources:
            if p.endswith(".patch"):
                tools.patch(base_path='opencv', patch_file=p, fuzz=True)

        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure(source_folder="opencv", args=self.cmake_flags())
        cmake.build()
        cmake.install()

    def package_info(self):
        self.cpp_info.libs = tools.collect_libs(self)
```

Conan version both in Windows and in Linux is 1.54.0

How do I correctly upload and consume the package?

**Update**.

After conversation with @drodri in comments I have removed `conanfile.py` from `exports_sources`, deleted all conan-generated files in all PCs and removed uploaded files from the Artifactory.

Then I've rebuilt the package, re-exported and re-uploaded it.

Comment: the flow is not clear. Why would you ``export`` the recipe if it is already in the server? Am I  missing a ``conan upload`` command first (and possibly a ``conan remove "*" -f``, to force the local removal and download it from the server)?

Comment: It seems you are using some "legacy" helpers, like that ``CMake`` instead of the one ``from conan.tools.cmake import CMake``, see https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/tools/cmake.html

Comment: The ``exports_sources = 'conanfile.py'```is unnecessary? Why would you export the conanfile.py itself? I'd probably suggest submitting an issue to https://github.com/conan-io/conan with the details above, to discuss things there.

Comment: I have adopted recipe from https://github.com/adamrehn/ue4-opencv-demo It is a bit outdated, indeed.

Comment: If you want to adopt something more actual, mature and sophisticate, you should take a look on https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/ as reference. There are good recipes there which you can use as reference.

Comment: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/master/recipes/opencv/3.x/conanfile.py - currently it is over sophisticated for me :). I think, I return to it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in restrictions of our Artifactory. Admins have forbidden uploading `.py` files.